# sort items in json_util_dumps in Tornado handler

Tags: python, json, tornado

I would like to output as the following (ordered like in my script).

```
{"data": [
    { "cid": "CG138712",
      "mac": "24-A4-3C-F6-51-21",
      "category": "CPE- E",
      "last_seen": "2017-12-11 12:42:10",                                                 
       "cpe-o": {"cid": "CS247314",
                 "mac":"80-2A-A8-7E-1D-8E",
                 "category": "CPE-O", 
                 "last_seen": "2018-05-14 15:28:42", 
               }
    }]
}
```

But my code keeps output like that.

```
{"data": [
        { "cid": "CG138712",
          "category": "CPE- E",                                                 
           "cpe-o": {"cid": "CS247314",
                     "last_seen": "2018-05-14 15:28:42", 
                     "category": "CPE-O", 
                     "mac":"80-2A-A8-7E-1D-8E"   
                   }
            "mac": "24-A4-3C-F6-51-21",
            "last_seen": "2017-12-11 12:42:10",
        }]
    }
```

This is how I implement in my script!

```
    cpeo_dict = dict(......)  
    doc = {"cid": document['cid'],"mac": document['mac'],"category": document['category'],"last_seen": document['last_seen'].strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),"cpe-o": cpeo_dict}
   docs_uplink.append(doc)
   dumped = json_util.dumps(dict(data=docs_uplink))
```

I can't find how to add parameters in json_util.dumps function, I only found sort and OrderedDict of json.dumps.

Answer (score 0):

Python dictionaries don't preserve order. There is a special class for preserving order in dicts - [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict). Instead of using `dict`, you need to use `OrderedDict`.

Example:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

doc = OrderedDict([
    ('cid', document['cid']),
    ('mac', document['mac']),
    ('category', document['category']),
    # ... other keys ...
])

docs_uplink.append(doc)
dumped = json_util.dumps(dict(data=docs_uplink))
```